# Racket what does the procedure

Tags: racket, procedure

I have a procedure but actually I don't know what it does.
Will anybody explain it?

```
(define (stj fun listt)
  (if (null? listt)
      `()
      (cons (fun (car listt)) (stj fun (cdr listt)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `map` procedure, check the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29). It takes a procedure and a list as parameters, and applies the procedure to each of the elements in the input list, producing an output list with the results:

```
(stj sqr '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 4 9 16 25)
```